# How to make responsive HTML table for email?

Tags: html, css

I try to make this table to be responsive but when I make a test 1st column and the last column are not fit for mobile. I use this for email template and create via template builder. On the desktop, table version is perfect but when I open through the mobile device the first column is on the 2 rows and also the last one.

How can I fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, date=no, address=no, email=no, url=no">
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
  <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
</head>
<body>
<table class="table" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;" borders="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th" style="background-color: whitesmoke; border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">Symbol</th>
      <th style="background-color: whitesmoke; border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; ">Last Price</th>
      <th style="background-color: whitesmoke; border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; ">Price Change%</th>
      <th style="background-color: whitesmoke; border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; ">Vol Yesterday (in $Mn)</th>
      <th style="background-color: whitesmoke; border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; ">Vol Change%</th>
      <th style="background-color: whitesmoke; border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; ">Market Cap (In $Bn)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">FIRST</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">$0.29</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; color: mediumseagreen;">68.11<span style="font-size: 8px; margin-left: 2px;">&#9650;</span></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">11.24M</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">7965.1%</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">0.01B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">SCND</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">$5.79</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; color: mediumseagreen;">47.7<span style="font-size: 8px; margin-left: 2px;">&#9650;</span></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">1.84B</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">320.67%</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">0.25B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">THRD</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">$2.04</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; color: mediumseagreen;">28.3<span style="font-size: 8px; margin-left: 2px;">&#9650;</span></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">1.47B</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">1323.71%</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">0.02B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">FRTH</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">$119.4</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; color: tomato;">-18.8<span style="font-size: 8px; margin-left: 2px;">&#9660;</span></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">0.42B</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">42.51%</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid gainsboro; padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">9.04B</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean "responsive"? HTML tables have a history not being used "responsibly".

Comment: I don't think you would be able to do this with inline css as you would need media queries at the very least - your issue is you have too much content and too many columns for it to fit on mobile screen so without media queries you can't make it responsive

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue you described (in Developer Tools)

Comment: How can I use media queries correctly?

Comment: Take a look to this library: https://github.com/smasala/responsive-tables-js

Comment: @TimR this is a mobile view.
https://i.ibb.co/d6yq7y2/image.png

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps consider using a framework like Bootstrap, it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).